# Await requires that the type 'TaskofX' have a suitable GetAwaiter Method

Tags: .net, vb.net, asynchronous, async-await

I've constructed a web service ("InvStatus") which contains a single function as follows:

```
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols
Imports System.Threading.Tasks


<WebService(Namespace:="http://example.com/InvStatus/", Name:="InvStatus",
        Description:="the description")>
<WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)>
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()>
Public Class InvStatus
Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

Public Structure CustomReturnStruct
    Dim firstItem As String
    Dim secondItem As integer
End Structure


<WebMethod()>
  Public Async Function LookupAsync(ByVal itemCode As String) 
       As Task(Of CustomReturnStruct)

    Dim result As New CustomReturnStruct

    ' ... look up the item, and stuff the results into 
    '     result.firstItem and result.seconditem 
    ' ...

    return result
  End Function
End Class
```

The services compiles fine, but when I attempt to call it from another program as a web reference:

```
dim myWebSvc As New com.example.InvStatus

--> Dim result As CustomReturnStruct = Await myWebSvc.LookupAsync("test123") <--
```

...gives a compiler error saying that 'Await' requires that the type TaskOfCustomReturnStruct have a suitable GetAwaiter method

What am I doing wrong? (and what's a GetAwaiter method??)

Comment: What version of .NET are you targeting? If you're targeting .NET 4.0 (instead of 4.5) that would explain things.

Comment: I'm targeting.Net 4.7 on the calling program end; the web service targets .Net 4.6.1

Comment: Okay, they it really should be fine...

Comment: Why did you name your service `LookupAsync` in the first place? *Clients* don't care at all - async calls are a *client* feature. You have to create a proxy with *asynchronous* methods*.  Your async method is probably called `LookupAsyncAsync`

Comment: Web service lifetime has nothing at all to do with the `async/await` keywords, it's controlled by WCF/ASMX. `async/await` affect how the *method* makes async calls to other services/databases

Comment: @pbickford you are calling a synchronous method instead of the async one. How did you generate the client proxy? By default, Task-based async methods are created, at least since VS 2012. That means that the async method is called `LookupAsyncAsync`. If you opted for the old-style asynchronous methods, you'll have `BeginLookupAsync` and `EndLookupAsync`.

Comment: I named the web service function LookupAsync to be consistent with the naming conventions I use in other types of programming. I did notice that AutoComplete did offer me a choice of LookupAsyncAsync when typing  the problematic line "Await MyWebSvc.[Lookup...]" which calls the web service. Trying "Await MyWebSvc.LookupAsyncAsync(<params>) results in "Expression does not produce a value". 

(I added the reference to my calling program with Add Service command.). I'll admit that I don't fully understand some of the mechanics of how proxies are generated in so doing.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos -- Are you saying that the web service should always be written using sync methods? (e.g. Open vs. OpenAsync for database connections?).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - It looks as if from the example here: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/600926/Asynchronous-web-services-call-in-ASP-NET that the automatically generated reference LookupAsyncAsync will always be void, and that I need to assign the result by implementing the LookupAsyncCompleted event in my client, and grabbing the return value from the e.result. (Why this can't be assigned directly by calling result = await LookupAsyncAsync(params) is beyond me).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Inconveniently, however, VS 2017 doesn't seem to automatically create the completed method anymore (LookupAsyncCompleted doesn't appear in my autocomplete options). This is truly maddening. It feels like I'm about 2 line of code away from a solution, but I'm missing some crucial piece of the understanding of the model to make getting the result back possible.

Comment: I do see a "LookupCompletedEventHandler", but I can't figure out how to make productive use of it. Man, if anyone can toss me a useful reference to resolve this situation, I'd be incredibly grateful.

Comment: @pbickford it does. *What* settings did you use to create the proxy? How did you add the service reference? I use both ASMX and WCF services, and all have asynchronous methods. Perhaps you opted for the old-style BeginXXX/EndXXX methods

Comment: @pbickford what does LookupAsyncCompleted  or event handlers have to do with asynchronous methods anyway? You should look either for BeginLookupAsync, if you opted for the old-style methods, or LookupAsyncAsync if you opted for the new

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I added it via Add Service > Advanced > Add Web Service. It created the LookupAsyncAsync procdure, but that one doesn't return a value -- I need to find a way to get the results back. The referenced article seemed to point to a solution, but it lacks working sample code, and recreating it in VS2017 didn't lead to the same Completed event being available. What would be the proper way to get a value back from LookupAsyncAsync?

Comment: @pbickford what does `it doesn't return a value` mean? What is its signature? Task? Task<CustomReturnStruct> ? Void?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the reference to LookupAsyncAsync was automatically created when adding my service as a web reference. In the References.vb of the calling code, it appears as:

Comment: Public Overloads Sub LookupAsync(byval ItemCode as string)
            Me.LookupAsyncAsync(byval ItemCode as string, Nothing)
        End Sub
        
        '''<remarks/>
        Public Overloads Sub LookupAsyncAsync(byval itemCode as string, ByVal userState As Object)
            If (Me.LookupOperationCompleted Is Nothing) Then
                Me.LookupOperationCompleted = AddressOf Me.OnLookupOperationCompleted
            End If
            Me.InvokeAsync("Lookup", New Object() {<Params>}, Me.LookupOperationCompleted, userState)
        End Sub

Comment: (So basically, it overloads as Sub, not Function) which becomes the equivalent of Void in C. The "real" method ("LookupAsync") meanwhile is a function defined as in the original message.